# Ошибка при подключении к postgreSQL из Visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, postgresql

Я пытаюсь реализовать клиентскую часть базы данных PosgreSql. Для создания подключения я передаю следующую строку подключения:

```
connectionString="Server=мой_ip,5432;Database=DB;User Id=мой_пользователь;Password=мой_пароль;"
```

При сборке приложения выходит ошибка: **"Подключение к серверу успешно установлено, но затем произошла ошибка в процессе подтверждения, предшествующего входу. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - Указанное сетевое имя более недоступно.)"**

С подключением к серверу всё в порядке. Тест подключения из VS проходит.
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

**UPD:** метод, откуда я подключаюсь к БД

```
private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StudentsCS"].ConnectionString;
            
            sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();

            listView1.GridLines = true;
            listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
            listView1.View = View.Details;

            listView1.Columns.Add("Id");
            listView1.Columns.Add("Name"); 
            listView1.Columns.Add("Surname"); 
            listView1.Columns.Add("Birthday");

            await LoadStudentsAsync();
        }
```

SudentsCS определил в App.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="StudentsCS" connectionString = "Server=****,5432;Database=DB;User Id=***;Password=***;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

  </connectionStrings>
```

**Версия БД:** "PostgreSQL 12.3, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit"

**Версия Npgsql:** 4.1.4

Comment: [На этом форуме](https://www.sql.ru/forum/1025821/podkluchenie-k-serveru-uspeshno-ustanovleno-no-zatem-proizoshla-oshibka-v-processe) смотрели последний пост в котором помог `перезапуск службы C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k rpcss` ?

Comment: @motpfofs У меня немного другой текст ошибки. У них: provider: "SSL Provider, error: 0 - Время ожидания операции истекло", а у меня: "provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - Указанное сетевое имя более недоступно."
Да я пробовал, не помогло.

Comment: Добавьте коду. И классы которые вы используете

Comment: Версию Postgres , Npgsql

Comment: @AzizUmarov добавил в вопрос. Npgsql оказывается не стоял на этом проекте. Я его добавил, но ничего не изменилось.

Comment: В конфиге `providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"` - это провайдер для SqlServer. А нужен для Postgres. | В коде `SqlConnection` - это класс для SqlServer. А нужен для Postgres.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov всё получилось, ошибку понял. Глупо получилось. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо **Alexander Petrov** и **Aziz Umarov** огромное за наводку.

Всё удалось исправить.
Добавил в импорты: `using Npgsql;`
И заменил классы SqlConnection на NpgsqlConnection:

```
private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StudentsCS"].ConnectionString;
            
            sqlConnection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);
            await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();

            listView1.GridLines = true;
            listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
            listView1.View = View.Details;

            listView1.Columns.Add("Id");
            listView1.Columns.Add("Name"); 
            listView1.Columns.Add("Surname"); 
            listView1.Columns.Add("Birthday");

            await LoadStudentsAsync();
        }
```

Строку подключения заменил на подходящую для этого класса:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="StudentsCS" connectionString="Server=****;Port=5432;Database=DB;User Id=***;Password=***;" providerName="Npgsql" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

И всё заработало как часы. Ещё раз спасибо всем кто помогал.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте
[NpgSql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/)
Провайдер .Net для Postgres базы данных.

Пример подключения и работы с [ним](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/index.html)

Comment: Спасибо, я всё понял.